# SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) - Decide data type at deploy time?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

does anyone know of a technique to decide the data type of a column at deploy time with SSDT / dacpac deployment, depending on what features are available on the target SQL Server instance? Concrete example:

```
CREATE TABLE [HasBlob] (
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Data] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
)
```

In this case, I would like to be able to automatically fall back to a conventional VARBINARY(MAX) blob instead of a FILESTREAM if FILESTREAM is not enabled for the SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to query the current database's filegroups via `sys.data_spaces`, for example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.data_spaces WHERE type = 'FD')
BEGIN
-- use create statement with FILESTREAM
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint - unfortunately I have no time to try it out at the moment since I've decided to ditch FILESTREAM for my project anyway because it gives me headaches regarding deployment. So I can't say if that approach works with incremental DACPAC deployment. So I just give you an accept, since I don't have time to try and prove you wrong ;-).